# Focused property is always true in Windows Forms control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus, gdi+

I am currently working on a Windows Forms control library, and as part of this, I am writing a custom button control. It's very similar to the standard Button control, but it does have some differences in the way that it's rendered. That being said, the code below is not a complete representation of what I am trying to achieve, but it does illustrate the point I am trying to make.

Here is an example of the code:

```
public class Button : System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase, IButtonControl
{
    public Button()
    {
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, 
                                          this.ClientRectangle.Height, 
                                          PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, 
                                          this.ClientRectangle, 
                                          this.Text, 
                                          this.Font, 
                                          TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter 
                                            | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter, 
                                          this.Focused, 
                                          this.GetButtonState());
            }
            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }   
}
```

This works fine, and renders the button appropriately, however, there is ALWAYS a Focused rectangle on the button, even when other objects on the form should be recieving focus (thus removing focus from the custom button), it is still being drawn with a focus rectangle.

Is there a reason for this? Why is the control not losing focus?

Comment: i updated my answer.. try it.

Comment: When it is in the state that should not be focussed, what happens if you resize the containing window? Does the focus rectangle disappear? If so, you have a problem with it not redrawing when the focussed state changes.

Comment: No repro with the provided code, it draws the focus rectangle just fine and omits it when the button doesn't have the focus.  Maybe it really *does* have the focus, the Control.Focused property never lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public Button()
    {
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);

    }
```

it removes the focus rectangle of the control.

Comment: This does not work because SetStyle is defined as SetStyle(ControlStyles, Boolean). Since "CanFocus" is Boolean, this would require a definition of SetStyle as such: SetStyle(Boolean, Boolean). Also, I want the button to be focusable, but I want it to update properly when it loses focus.

Comment: This is better, thanks for the update, however, I want my button to get/lose focus like any other focusable control, but I want it to lose focus properly...maybe I need to force a redraw on the OnGotFocus and OnLostFocus methods. That being said, +1 for effort! :-)